# Multiple key presses in JavaScript only working in IE

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
function handle_paste_keydown(key)
{   
    if(key.keyCode == 86 && key.ctrlKey) // Ctrl + V
    {
        alert("Test...");
    }
}
```

This works in IE, but none of the other browsers. My reason for doing this is that I have finished creating a rich-text editor, but I need to handle the onpaste event carefully because formatted text is able to make it in to my editor, which could pose a minor risk to security, but also butchers my layout if malicious `<span>`s and `<div>`s make it in.

My current method is to give focus to an off-screen textarea, which means all code will be pasted in to that (which removes formatting); then I immediately grab the textarea.value and insert it at the current caret position in my contentEditable `<div>`.

So anyway, how do I get the Ctrl+V to work in all browsers *and* why doesn't it work in its current state?

Thank you.

Comment: Your code works for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/Ssu2x/ What do you get if you `alert(key.keyCode)` before the if? (Also, are you handling paste via the context menu or the browser's _Edit_ menu? How about drag'n'drop?)

Comment: If I alert the event before my if statement, then I get a single keycode being given. My function is called onkeydown for the <div>, so will always display a single keypress if alerted before the if statement. I am handling paste by disabling the paste option entirely (onpaste = "return false;"), and allowing only Ctrl+V so I may handle pre-formatted text. Interestingly, I tried the link you gave and it works for me in Chrome also. This is strange behaviour? I can't think of a reason why my web site won't allow the code to work, but works fine on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If it works in IE but nowhere else you did something wrong.

Use the keypress event rather than keydown.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lxvgr/1/

```
document.getElementById('foo').onkeypress = function(e) {
    if(e.charCode == 118 && e.ctrlKey) alert('pasted');        
};
```

@Eric Sites: "use jQuery" isn't the answer to every javascript question.  including an entire external framework to solve a simple 4byte issue like this is ridiculous.

Comment: Hi guys, I solved the problem. It was nothing to do with the code, but my conditional statements. I had if(document.selection), with my code inside that. Sorry to waste time here, I need to be more thorough in my checking. The correct way to handle it is to use document.selection for IE<9 with window.getSelection() for non-IE browsers and IE>9.